# Why doesn't inline-flex / inline-grid behave consistently as with inline in contenteditable?

Tags: html, css

When I use **display: inline-flex;** or **display: inline-grid;** there seems to be some added "spaces" or some kind of extra focused calculations take place.  I'm not sure exactly what's happening.  When using the arrow keys to navigate through a contentediatble div, the caret gets stuck as if it is focusing on a different element or something.  Does anyone know the reason why?  And if so, anyways to prevent this behavior (not using JavaScript to handle the events)?

Consider the difference between the two following contenteditable divs:

(The caret gets "stuck" in between "Hello" and "World" when navigating with arrow keys)

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><span style="display: inline-flex;"><span>Hello</span></span><span style="display: inline-flex;">World!</span></div>

<div contenteditable="true"><span style="display: inline;"><span>Hello</span></span><span style="display: inline;">World!</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is a one-dimensional layout system that we can use to create a row or a column axis layout. In `display: flex` property, every element that you have inside that flex parent container turns into a flex item. So, the caret gets "stuck" in-between "Hello" and "World" when navigating with arrow keys.

CSS grid is a two-dimensional layout system, we can work with rows and columns together. It opens a lot of different possibilities to build more complex and organized design systems.

*"CSS grid is for layout, Flexbox is for alignment"*. More Reference [Grid and flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout), [When it uses Grid and FlexBox](https://blog.logrocket.com/flexbox-vs-css-grid/)

**flex:**
This value causes an element to generate a block-level flex container box.

**inline-flex:**
This value causes an element to generate an inline-level flex container box.

**grid:**
This value causes an element to generate a block-level grid container box.

**inline-grid:**
This value causes an element to generate an inline-level grid container box.

You can use the below codes to prevent *The caret gets "stuck" in-between "Hello" and "World" when navigating with arrow keys)*.

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><span style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 2px">Hello</span><span style="display: inline-block;" >World!</span></div>

<div contenteditable="true"><span style="display: inline-block;">Hello</span><span style="display: inline-block;" >World!</span></div>

<div contenteditable="true" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;"><span>Hello</span><span>World!</span></div>
```

Comment: Using "display: inline-block;" doesn't fix the problem as I need to use either "inline-flex" or "inline-grid".

Comment: I'm also looking for a technical explanation of the why that a flex item gets hung up by position.  What is the calculations that take place?

Answer (score 0):

These are definitions of `flex,inline-flex,space-between`.
so using `flex and space-between` you can give space between elements.

display -
flex         :  Displays an element as a block-level flex container
inline-flex  :  Displays an element as an inline-level flex container

justify-content -
space-between   Items are positioned with space between the lines
ANSWERS:

OPTION 1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" style="background-color: cornflowerblue;"><span
            style="display: inline-flex;"><span>Hello</span></span><span
            style="display: inline-flex;color: white;">World!</span></div>

    <div contenteditable="true" style="display: flex ;justify-content: space-between;background-color: coral;"><span
            style="display: inline;background-color: cyan;"><span style="color: white;">Hello</span></span><span
            style="display: inline;">World!</span></div>
            
    <div contenteditable="true" style="display: inline-flex;background-color: coral;">
        <span style="display: inline;background-color: cyan;"><span style="color: white;">Hello</span></span><span
            style="display: inline;">World!</span></div>

</body>

</html>
```

you can also use `justify-content: space-between` to give space between `Hello World!`

OPTION 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" style="background-color: cornflowerblue;" ><span style="display: inline-flex;"><span>Hello</span></span><span style="display: inline-flex;color: white;">World!</span></div>

<div contenteditable="true" style="display: flex;justify-content: space-between;background-color: coral;"><span style="display: inline;background-color: cyan;"><span style="color: white;">Hello</span></span><span style="display: inline;">World!</span></div>
<div contenteditable="true" style="justify-content: space-between;background-color: coral;"><span style="display: inline;background-color: cyan;"><span style="color: white;">Hello</span></span><span style="display: inline;">World!</span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is same as OPTION 1
if you follow first option you should put both `display: flex ;justify-content: space-between;` but if you follow second option then you should put only `justify-content: space-between;` and `display: flex ;` is optional.

Comment: This still doesn't deal with why the 'inline-flex' item gets "caught".  Why does it get caught?  What kind of browser calculations take place?  These solutions behave exactly the same as in my question.  I'm not looking to put a gap in between the elements.  The 'inline-flex' should behave in the same way that 'inline' does.  Are there any workarounds?